# call method when Variable changes value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a BOOL defined in my app delegate.m, and then in view controller.h I have

```
extern BOOL usingInternet;
```

And now I want to call a method anytime this value changes, I am trying

```
[usingInternet addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myData" options:0 context:@"data"];
```

But I get a compile error, `Bad receiver type BOOL` how can I call a method every time this bool changes value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"usingInternet" options:0 context:nil];
```

and get result from

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", keyPath, @(usingInternet), change);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call addObserver on a BOOL; you need to call it on an object. You can wrap the BOOL in an NSNumber.